# How to create Label text slider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have created slider in my app. How to add loop in my code. Because my label text slide only one time but i want to label text repeat (loop) on label. How it possible?

## My Label slider code

Make globalCounter as global variable

```
globalCounter=0;
if(nameArray.count>0){

[self changeLable];

}
```

Then

```
-(void)changeLable{

if(!(globalCounter<nameArray.count)){
    return;
}


NSLog(@"globalCounter %d",globalCounter);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^{


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [lblTitle setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                     globalCounter++;

                     [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

                 }];


}
```

## Edit

```
-(void)changeLable{

if(!(globalCounter<nameArray.count)){ 
 globalCounter=0; 
  }


NSLog(@"globalCounter %d",globalCounter);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^{


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [lblTitle setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                     globalCounter++;

                     [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

                 }];


 }
```

Comment: use web view instead of label and apply marquee effect to your text using html syntax

Comment: Use [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397122/how-to-move-text-from-right-to-left-in-ios-programatically/22397613#22397613

Comment: No No I don't want marquee effects , I want to change text on label some seconds like this (Image slider)

Comment: please add image screen shot, so we all are understood what you need actually.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351943/how-to-create-a-custom-uislider/39352460#39352460

Comment: your coding is fine what the issue u faced and where u struck

Comment: OP wants to change label text from array of values with animation like sliding text and set another text with sliding effect, i think right?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik My problem is that only one time change label text. but i want loop wise repeat my array

Comment: @RonakChaniyara You are right

Comment: change this line  [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; and try once

Comment: decrease the time interval and try once

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Please explain some code, How to use NSTimer in my code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried and change time interval but do not repeat my array

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I want only repeat my array (loop wise) because label text continues slide

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860254/how-to-make-marquee-uilabel-uitextfield-nstextfield

Comment: @user3182143 I do not use marquee label i used only normal label and text change on label by loop

Comment: Try with this below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
globalCounter=0;
if(des.count>0){
     [_label setText:[des objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
    [self changeLable];

}
```

and call method like

```
-(void)changeLable{

if(globalCounter < des.count){



[UIView animateWithDuration:0.
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^{


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     if(globalCounter>=des.count){
                         globalCounter=0;//set counter to zero after it exceeds array count to repeat text change round repeated
                     }else
                     {
                          [_label setText:[des objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                         globalCounter++;
                         [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
                     }




                 }];
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it may help:

```
-(void)changeLable{

NSLog(@"globalCounter %d",globalCounter);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^{

                     [lblTitle setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    if(globalCounter>nameArray.count)){

                       globalCounter=0;//set counter to zero after it exceeds array count to repeat text change round repeated

                    }else{

                       globalCounter++;

                    }

                     [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

                 }];

}
```

Comment: I'm using your code but array first round completed after crash my app error show below :- -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: Error.I tried your code now and it crashed.Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Comment: check your count not exceed on array count

Comment: @ankurkumawat - check the updated answer bro, else attach your project here

Comment: @ankurkumawat - ok attach your project here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik resolve my problem please check my updated code in Edit

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer brother.Sorry I could not answer immediately as I had some work.I downloaded and ran your project.First it crashes as you handled the wrong array count.So it bounds the array.After that I set the condition inside the black.

```
-(void)changeLable
{

  NSLog(@"globalCounter %d",globalCounter);

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^{

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     if(globalCounter<des.count)
                     {
                        _label.text = @"";
                        [_label setText:[des objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                        globalCounter++;
                     }
                     else
                      globalCounter=0;
                   [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
            }];
}
```